# Running script for Wheezy customizations for DSE

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I keep getting an error when trying to configure Datastax Enterprise (my first Cassandra cluster) on Google Cloud Platform, specifically when following the tutorial here: 
[DataStax Enterprise Deployment Guide for Google Compute Engine - Manual](https://academy.datastax.com/demos/datastax-enterprise-deployment-guide-google-compute-engine-manual)

`ssh` into new machine called `customizer`

When I copy and paste the script, or completely retype the script on `pico` or `vi` (script found under "Create a customized OS image") and try to run it I get the error  `./customizer.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'` because of this line:

```
patch --backup /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount < #MOUNT_OPTIONS="discard,defaults" > MOUNT_OPTIONS="defaults,discard,noauto,noatime,barrier=0"
SFAM
```

Any idea what this line should look like to not get this error? When I try to remove the `<` and `>` the terminal gets hung up and i have to ctrl+c to get out.

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#This script can be applied to a running GCE instance
#to prep it for running DSE on SSD based storage, assumed
#to be mounted at /dev/sdb. After this script has been applied,
#a GCE image can be created accordin to the instructions at the
#Image creation guide: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#creatingimage
#Base OS list: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#backportsimages

apt-get update
apt-get install -y less htop patch libjna-java sysstat iftop binutils pssh pbzip2 zip unzip openssl curl liblzo2-dev ntp git python-pip tree unzip dstat ethtool

#Don't need to disable swap
#Disable Swap
#swapoff -a

#Need to mount SSD
mkdir -p /var/lib/cassandra
#https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#formatting
#/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F"  
patch --backup /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount < #MOUNT_OPTIONS="discard,defaults"
> MOUNT_OPTIONS="defaults,discard,noauto,noatime,barrier=0"
SFAM

patch --backup /etc/rc.local < echo deadline > /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
> echo 0 > /sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational
> blockdev --setra 0 /dev/sdb
> /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" /dev/sdb /var/lib/cassandra
>
END

cat >> /etc/sysctl.conf <
```

Comment: I was able to ssh from Mac OS X terminal by specifying the zone with:
`gcloud compute ssh customizer --zone us-central1-b` so that problem is ok but the "newline" error is still persisting!

Comment: Can you post the full content of your `customizer.sh` script please.

Comment: @morficus ok i updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out and sorry for the inconvenience - this is actually an issue with our documentation. Some of the characters were stripped out when we moved to a new content management system. We are in the process of fixing this as soon as possible.

In the meantime, please use this latest deployment guide for deploying Datastax Enterprise to Google:
https://academy.datastax.com/demos/deployment-guide-google

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 21 and 22 with the following:

From

```
patch --backup /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount < #MOUNT_OPTIONS="discard,defaults"
> MOUNT_OPTIONS="defaults,discard,noauto,noatime,barrier=0"
```

to this (note that this is still 2 lines):

```
patch --backup /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount
> MOUNT_OPTIONS="defaults,discard,noauto,noatime,barrier=0"
```

or this (note that this 1 lines would replace 21 and 22):

```
patch --backup /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount < MOUNT_OPTIONS="defaults,discard,noauto,noatime,barrier=0"
```

The reason for the error is because the end of line 21 is commented out (everything after the `#` symbol) so it is technically ending in the `<` character... which is used for command substation.

Comment: The first suggestion leads to the system "hanging up" and having me to press "ctrl+c" to abort the call. 
The second suggestion leads to the error of:

`./customize.sh: line 12:    MOUNT_OPTIONS=defaults,discard,noauto,noatime,barrier=0: No such file or directory`

`./customize.sh: line 13: SFAM: command not found`

Comment: Are you sure that the script hung and that it wasn't still running? How long did you let it sit before killing the process with ctrl+c?

Comment: Just ran it for 30+ minutes and not a single print out!